# Confusing example about '&&' and '||' precedence

Tags: java, java-7, operator-precedence

I was testing the precedence between `&&` and `||` and I had an example that was confusing. In Java, `&&` has higher operator precedence than the operator `||`.

So if we have those 3 expressions:

```
//expr1  = true , expr2 = false; expr3 = false;

if(expr1 || expr2 && expr3);
```

It should be evaluated as:

```
if(expr1 || (expr2 && expr3));
```

So `expr2 && expr3` should be evaluated before `expr1`. However, this example:

```
int a1 = 10;
int a2 = 20;
System.out.println(a1 < a2 || ++a1 > a2 && ++a2 < a1);
System.out.println(a1);
System.out.println(a2);
```

Outputs:

```
true
10
20
```

That proves that only  `a1 < a2` is evaluated.
Can you explain why this is the case?

Comment: The operators also short-circuit.

Comment: precedence != order of evaluation. `expr2` and `expr3` are grouped by it still evaluates left to right.

Comment: I find Eric Lippert's article on [Precedence vs Associativity vs Order](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/05/23/precedence-vs-associativity-vs-order/) to be a good explanation of this. It's about C#, not Java, but the important thing is the distinction between order of evaluation and operator precedence, which is equally applicable here.

Comment: I know this is old but maybe you're thinking PEMDAS but in this case the || operator is evaluated before parenthesis

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The expression is [short-circuiting](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). From the link:

> when the first argument of the AND function evaluates to false, the overall value must be false; and when the first argument of the OR function evaluates to true, the overall value must be true.

It sees that the rest of the condition doesn't matter because one of the operands of `||` is already true (10 < 20). If one of the operands is true, then no matter what the rest of the condition is, it's true.

You may use bitwise `&` and `|` to prevent this.

---

> But, the ( expr2 && expr3 ) should be evaluated before expr1, no ?

No. You have to separate concepts of **precedence** and **evaluation order**.

- **Precedence**: Dictates *the parenthesization* of an expression, not the order in which an expression is evaluated. For an example:

  ```
    true || false && false
  ```

  Is parenthesized to this because `&&` has higher precedence than `||`:

  ```
    true || (false && false)
  ```

  This does not mean that things in parentheses is evaluated first in Java's case. Precedence just clarifies what the operands of an operator are, in this case `false` and `false`, where as in *this* case:

  ```
    (true || false) && (false || false)
  ```

  The operands for `&&` are `true` and `false`, not `false` and `false`.
- **Evaluation Order**: Describes in what order each operand is evaluated and operator is applied and is sometimes language specific. This dictates how an expression is evaluated, unlike precedence.

In this case, your example:

```
true || false && false
```

As established earlier, becomes this due to precedence:

```
true || (false && false)
```

But Java, unlike C++, JavaScript, or a number of other languages has a strictly left to right evaluation. Per the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/):

> #### 15.7. Evaluation Order
>
> The Java programming language guarantees that the operands of operators appear to be evaluated in a specific evaluation order, namely, from left to right.
>
> #### 15.7.1. Evaluate Left-Hand Operand First
>
> The left-hand operand of a binary operator appears to be fully evaluated before any part of the right-hand operand is evaluated.

So, when you have:

```
true || (false && false)
```

Java *first evaluates the left operand* which turns out to be `true`. Then the whole condition short circuits. The right operand of `||` in the parentheses is never evaluated at all. The same goes for your other example:

```
a1 < a2 || (++a1 > a2 && ++a2 < a1)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
           Step 0, precedence and parenthesization
```

---

```
a1 < a2 || (++a1 > a2 && ++a2 < a1)
^^^^^^^
Step 1, left operand evaluated, variables resolved to values 10 and 20, condition is true
```

---

```
true || (++a1 > a2 && ++a2 < a1)
^^^^
Step 2, short circuits, left operand is not evaluated
```

---

Take another more complex example:

```
false || false || true && (false || true) || false
```

Due to precedence, it becomes:

```
false || false || (true && (false || true)) || false
```

Then, evaluation begins, left to right:

```
false || false || (true && (false || true)) || false
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Step 1, false || false, does not short circuit, right operand is evaluated, is false
```

---

```
false || (true && (false || true)) || false
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Step 2, false || (true && (false || true)), does not short circuit, right operand is evaluated
Step 2A, (true && (false || true)), does not short circuit, right operand is evaluated
Step 2B, (false || true), does not short circuit, right operand is evaluated, is true
Step 2C, (true && true), does not short circuit, right operand is evaluated, is true
Step 2D, false || true, does not short circuit, right operand is evaluated, is true
```

---

```
true || false
^^^^
Step 3, true || false short circuits, right operand is not evaluated, is true
```

---

Thus the whole expression evaluates to `true`. The whole expression was evaluated left to right the whole way through. Precedence only dictated the operands of an operator via parenthesization, not the evaluation order.

Further reading at [Eric Lippert's explanatory article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/05/23/precedence-vs-associativity-vs-order/) on precedence vs associativity vs evaluation order as mentioned by [Daniel Pryden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40071805/java-confusing-example-about-and-precedence#comment67427490_40071805), it clears up a lot of the confusion.

The main takeaway is that *precedence* does not dictate in what an expression is evaluated. It only dictates how an expression should be parenthesized. *Evaluation order*, on the other hand, tells us exactly how an expression is evaluated, and in Java's case is **always** left to right.

Answer (score 6):

The first line prints `true` because of short-circuiting the `||` operator.

`a1 < a2` is true and so the rest of the boolean expression doesn't need to be evaluated and `true` is returned.

> expr2 should be evaluated before expr1

is incorrect, as operator precedence affects the structure of the expression, rather then the evaluation order (in most cases). If you were to re-order the expression so that it was `(expr2 && expr3) || expr1`, then yes, `expr2` would be evaluated before `expr1`

Answer (score 5):

**Precedence:**

```
boolean result = a || b && c
```

In order to have the correct value according to the rules of precedence, the compiler must logically evaluate this as:

```
boolean x = b && c
boolean result = a || x
```

This speaks to your point that `b && c` must be evaluated before `result` can be calculated.  However, in Boolean algebra, it is possible to write expressions whose results *do not depend on all the operands*.  This fact is exploited to enable a compiler optimization called *short circuiting*.

**Short Circuiting:**

For any Boolean expression:

```
a || b
```

the result does not depend on `b` if `a` evaluates to `true`.  When `a` is `true`, it does not matter if `b` evaluates to true or false.  Because of this, the compiler executes:

```
a || b && c
```

as if it had been written:

```
boolean result = a;
if (!a) result = b && c;
```

Note that executed this way, the rules of precedence are still respected.  The expression is not evaluated as `(a || b) && c`.  Since the overall result of the expression does not depend on `(b && c)` in the case where `a` is true, `b && c` is simply never evaluated.

This is a good thing.  Short circuiting allows you to write correct programs when the correctness of one operand depends on the correctness of another.  For example:

```
if (myString == null || !myString.isEmpty() && myString != "break") return;
```

Without short circuit evaluation, the boolean expression could throw a `NullPointerException`.  However, because of short circuit evaluation, this expression, as written, can never throw a `NullPointerException`.

Short circuiting can also be used as a performance optimization.  If evaluating one operand is extremely expensive, evaluating another first can save the execution time needed to evaluate an operand whose value does not influence the final result of the whole expression.

Answer (score 3):

Even when you use explicit parentheses as in

```
if (expr1 || (expr2 && expr3))
```

`expr1` is evaluated first, since the operands of operators are evaluated from left to right. Since `||` is a short circuited operator, the second operand (`(expr2 && expr3)` in your case) will only be evaluated if `expr1` is `false`.

When you remove the parentheses, the operator precedence only comes into play if `expr1` is false. In that case the `&&` operand will be evaluated before the `||` operator and its value will be the second operand of the `||` operator.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of short-circuiting. Where the first expression is evaluated first and if it's able to derive the result as true then it concludes there & would not even go for rest of the expression.If the first expression results as false then the other condition will be checked and the outcome will be derived.

To know more on operator precedence. Please refer below.

https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/